# Parsing a json gives JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing

I have a document with new-line-delimited json's, to which I apply some functions. Everything works up until this line, which looks exactly like this:

```
{"_id": "5f114", "type": ["Type1", "Type2"], "company": ["5e84734"], "answers": [{"title": " answer 1", "value": false}, {"title": "answer 2 ", "value": true}, {"title": "This is a title.", "value": true}, {"title": "This is another title", "value": true}], "audios": [null], "text": {}, "lastUpdate": "2020-07-17T06:24:50.562Z", "title": "This is a question?", "description": "1000 €.", "image": "image.jpg", "__v": 0}
```

The entire code:

```
import json  

def unimportant_function(d):
    d.pop('audios', None)
    return {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v != {}}


def parse_ndjson(data):
    return [json.loads(l) for l in data.splitlines()]

with open('C:\\path\\the_above_example.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as handle:
    data = handle.read()
    dicts = parse_ndjson(data)

for d in dicts:
    new_d = unimportant_function(d)
    json_string=json.dumps(new_d, ensure_ascii=False)
    print(json_string)
```

The error `JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 260 (char 259)` happens at `dicts = parse_ndjson(data)`. Why? I also have no idea what that symbol after "answer 2" is, it didn't appear in the data but it appeared when I copy pasted it.

What is the problem with the data?

Comment: Can you try changing the `true` to `True` and the `false ` to `False` ? same for `null` to `None` as those are the expected keyword for python.

Comment: @JulesCivel the string is a JSON, so it should be `true` and not `True` for it to be a valid JSON.

Comment: I tried doing `json.loads('<the_JSON>')` and it worked for me. I do not know exactly how to reproduce the error.

Comment: "I also have no idea what that symbol after "answer 2" is" I don't see any unusual symbol in what you pasted.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel when using `json.loads()` the dictionary contains this: `{'title': 'answer 2\u2029', 'value': True}`. The `\u2029` character is the one I think he is talking about.

Comment: @JulesCivel In some previous lines, true and false were written the same way and I had no problem parsing them.

Comment: @SherlockBourne Eureka. I wasn't aware of this behaviour, but when I realized the string contained an unprintable character, I looked it up and the mystery unraveled itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unprintable character embedded in the `"answer 2"` string is a [paragraph separator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm), which is treated as whitespace by `.splitlines()`:

```
>>> 'foo\u2029bar'.splitlines()
['foo', 'bar']
```

(Speculation: the ndjson file might be exploiting this to represent "this string should have a newline in it", working around the file format. If so, it should probably be using a `\n` escape instead.)

The character is, however, *not* treated specially if you iterate over the lines of the file normally:

```
>>> # For demonstration purposes, I create a `StringIO`
>>> # from a hard-coded string. A file object reading
>>> # from disk will behave similarly.
>>> import io
>>> for line in io.StringIO('foo\u2029bar'):
...     print(repr(line))
...
'foo\u2029bar'
```

So, the simple fix is to make `parse_ndjson` expect a sequence of lines already - don't call `.splitlines`, and fix the calling code appropriately. You can either pass the open `handle` directly:

```
def parse_ndjson(data):
    return [json.loads(l) for l in data]

with open('C:\\path\\the_above_example.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as handle:
    dicts = parse_ndjson(handle)
```

or pass it to `list` to create a list explicitly:

```
def parse_ndjson(data):
    return [json.loads(l) for l in data]

with open('C:\\path\\the_above_example.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as handle:
    dicts = parse_ndjson(list(handle))
```

or create the list using the provided `.readlines()` method:

```
def parse_ndjson(data):
    return [json.loads(l) for l in data]

with open('C:\\path\\the_above_example.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as handle:
    dicts = parse_ndjson(handle.readlines())
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I now understand where the problem lies in the code. I know it’s a silly question but by passing the open handle directly do you mean I simply remove the parse_ndjson function?

Comment: this is correct, with the mention that if one copies the code 1:1 there won't be any defined "data" name because one passes the open handle directly. I wish I could edit but I can't :/

Comment: Typo (each time in the `with` block, `data` should be `handle`). Fixed.